# Sitecore Media library: Incorrect CSS mime type

Tags: css, sitecore, mime, sitecore7, sitecore-media-library

I'm trying to upload a css file through Sitecore 7 media library. 
Once the file is uploaded the MIME type created is, **application/octet-stream** and not **text/css**.

I already tweaked the configuration file as follows,

```xml
    <mediaType extension="css">
      <mimeType>text/css</mimeType>
      <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
    </mediaType>
```

Is there any work around?

Comment: What version of sitecore are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore is using text/css MIME Type for css files by default (Tested on sitecore 6.6, 7.0 and 7.2). The MIME Type is already configured in /App_Config/MimeTypes.config - so you don`t need to register it again.

You can check if there is override somewhere in the code by going to the compiled configuration file http://yoursite.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx. If something is overriding it try to locate where it comes from and remove it.

Here is how the MIME Type is set to a brand new 7.2 Instance.
[image]

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 7.0 I tested the same in an uncomplied sitecore instance. I still get the same MIME type.

Comment: @Arun have you checked the compiled config file for overrides ? I just tested it on 7.0 and it is working fine the only way to reproduce it is by removing the extension at all from the config files or replacing the css mimetype in MimeTypes.config with application/octet-stream

Comment: '<param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">css,js</param>' Will this cause any problem? I found this in config file.

Comment: @Arun - this is default and expected behaviour. I am more intrested in your mediaTypes node. Does it have css there ?

Comment: @Arun - can you check your MimeTypes.config and see if there is css there ? Because this file gets loaded after the other includes - so it will override everything before it